# Process multiple images using npm sightengine, I get "TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js, fs

I get "TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function" when I try to return some data from sightengine API from pictures.

Here is the loop I am using on a Vuejs project:

````
    async runBlurDetector() {
      console.log("Images uploaded")
      console.log(this.images)

      for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
        this.images[i].url = URL.createObjectURL(this.images[i]);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.images[i].image = reader.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.images[i]);
        await this.blurDetector(this.images[i]);
      }
    },

    blurDetector(image) {
      console.log("Blur Detector Starting....");
      console.log(image)

      sightengine.check(['properties']).set_file("../assets/images/" + image.name).then(function (result) {
        // The result of the API
        console.log(result)
      }).catch(function (err) {
        // Error
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  }```

I get the following error:

```TypeError: fs.createReadStream is not a function
    at Object.client.set_file (sightengine.js?cdad:37:1)
    at VueComponent.blurDetector (Dashboard.vue?98fa:94:1)```
````

Comment: In the sightengine docs it says `set_file('/full/path/to/image.jpg')` - you're using a relative path there, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I also tried it with set_file("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Pictures\\images\\BlurryDavid.jpg") and I get the same error. @James